# How to override default System.Resources.ResourceManager in Resources.Designer.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources

I want to override `System.Resources.ResourceManager` from `Resources.Designer.cs` file to achieve custom ResourceManager.GetString(...) method functionality. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you wrap ResourceManager instead of overriding it?

Comment: Yes I can. All I want to get is custom ResourceManager.GetString(...) functionality.

Comment: Then just wrap it in custom class and do all extra work in GetString method of that class.

Comment: And what about auto regenerate of `Resources.Designer.cs` with `ResXFileCodeGenerator`/`PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` when resource added/changed?

Comment: Couldn't you add an extension method to ResourceManager ?

Comment: I'm using ordinary resx files and ResourceManager wrapper. Never had a real need for resource designer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're asking two separate questions here. You can certainly override `ResourceManager.GetString`. You can't, however, use that override in the auto-generated `Resource.Designer.cs` code. To use it, you'll have to write your own `Resource` designer class.

```
public class MyResourceManager : System.Resources.ResourceManager
{
  // override
  public override GetString(string name)
  {
    // custom code
  }
}

public class MyResourceDesigner
{
  // use your custom class with override
  private static MyResourceManager resourceManager;
  private static CultureInfo resourceCulture;

  public static MyResourceManager ResourceManager
  {
    get
    {
      if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceManager, null))
      {
        // Resource is just the name of the .resx file
        // be sure to include relevant namespaces
        var temp = new MyResourceManager(
            "MyProject.Resource", 
            typeof(MyResourceDesigner).Assembly);
        resourceManager = temp;
      }

      return resourceManager;
    }
  }

  public static CultureInfo Culture
  {
    get
    {
      return resourceCulture;
    }

    set
    {
      resourceCulture = value;
    }
  }

  // start adding strongly-typed objects
  public static string Foo
  {
    get
    {
      // use your override
      return ResourceManager.GetString("Foo", resourceCulture);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not meant to be complete, though it is missing a `class` keyword. Try to make your criticism constructive, please.

Answer (score 6):

I created a `CustomResourceManager` that overrides the `GetString()` calls like so:

```
public class CustomResourceManager : ResourceManager
{
    public CustomResourceManager(Type resourceSource)
        :base(resourceSource)
    {
    }

    public CustomResourceManager(string baseName, Assembly assembly)
        : base(baseName, assembly)
    {
    }

    public CustomResourceManager(string baseName, Assembly assembly, Type usingResourceSet)
        : base(baseName, assembly, usingResourceSet)
    {
    }

    public override string GetString(string name)
    {
        // your business logic
    }

    public override string GetString(string name, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // your business logic
    }
}
```

Then I added a pre-build step to my project to replace the creation of a `System.Resources.ResourceManager` with my `CustomResourceManager` in the generated `Resource.Designer.cs` file:

```
powershell -command "(gc ..\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs).Replace(\"new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager\", \"new CustomResourceManager\") | set-content ..\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs -Encoding UTF8"
```

And away we go!

Comment: This works great, as long as resources are being used from code. When using resources from razor views it seems the original generated version is being used instead of the "adapted" version which is compiled. Any idea?

Comment: The custom resource manager is being called from the view for me. What does your view look like? My sample looks like this:
`@using My.Namespace.Resources` [new line]
`<h1>@Resource.Foo</h1>`

Comment: That seems to be exactly what we're doing, but it still doesn't work. When we check where the resources in the view point to we end up in this App_GlobalResources.gecvukmg.dll and not in the designer code file.
So it seems that the generated (and manipulated) designer code file is not used in the compiled App_GlobalResources.gecvukmg.dll used by the View.

Comment: Just to make sure we really have the same situation, how are the properties for your resx files set? Mine are as follows:
- build action: embedded resource;
- copy to output directory: do not copy;
- custom tool: publicresxfilecodegenerator;
- custom tool namespace: resources;

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the using a powershell command for replacing the ResourceManager can be found here: [ResXFileCodeGenerator - overriding the output (want to use a Custom ResourceManager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987762/resxfilecodegenerator-overriding-the-output-want-to-use-a-custom-resourcemana)

This uses reflection to replace the resouceMan property of the autogenerated static resource class during startup, like this:

```
var innerField = typeof(Resources.Resources).GetField("resourceMan",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

if (innerField != null)
{
    innerField.SetValue(null,
    new ExtendedResourceManager("MyNamespace.ResourceFileWithoutResx",
        typeof(Resources.Resources).Assembly));
}

innerField = typeof(Resources.Resources).GetField("resourceCulture",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

innerField.SetValue(null, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```